# How to specify the number maximum of points in the cluster using DBSCAN?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I know that DBSCAN have one parameter that specify the number minimum of points(min points) but I would like to restrict with the maximum number of points on a cluster? Do you know how can I do? I have investigated but i haven't found anything... For example, per cluster I only want to have a maximum of 4 points to be grouped by dbscan
Thanks!

Comment: You need to focus your question, and provide a code example of the context in which you want to make the specification you mention. As it is, you question i too vague to be answered (unless someone make many lucky guesses).

Comment: Max points per cluster is not defined in the DBSCAN algorithm. You would need to implement your own algorithm to decide what to do with larger groups.

Comment: Amitai irron, I edited the question :), for example, per cluster I only want to have a maximum of 4 points to be grouped by dbscan, did I notice?thanks!

Comment: You should take a look at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html for a good overview on a lot of different clustering algorithms, and how they compare.

Comment: Thanks Aaron! Do you recommend something in special? :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find everything you need in the link Aaron shared with you.  Also, just so you know, clustering methodologies are unsupervised, so you don't train/test anything.  You let the algo tell you the story, based on the data that is fed in.  You don't know what will happen in advance.  In short, with DBSCAN and also Hierarchical Clustering (but not K-Means), you do not pre-specify the number of clusters.  The algo determines the optimal number of clusters for you.  If you really want to control the number of clusters (min or max) you need to use a K-Means algo.  Take a look at this link when you have a chance.

https://blog.cambridgespark.com/how-to-determine-the-optimal-number-of-clusters-for-k-means-clustering-14f27070048f